# Is it possible to distinguish 2 POST methods with same URL in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, controller

In my app I can create and update entities. The problem is I can not merge this 2 methods in one createOrUpdate method with POST mapping and check whether object is new or not(That's because ID is not auto-generated, provided by a user). 
I ended up with making one of the methods create(POST mapping) and update(PUT mapping). But after a while I knew that in Spring the one is not capable of requesting parameters, if the method is PUT.
So, I guess I should use 2 POST methods for that, but they have the same URL pattern, since that my app can not work properly.

Is it possible to make something like that?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/users")
/.../
@PostMapping (//specific param here to distinguish???)
public void create(User user) 
{
service.save(user);
}

@PostMapping(//specific param here to distinguish???)
public void update(User user) 
{
service.update(user);
}

function save() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", //specific param here to distinguish?
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $("#editRow").modal("hide");
            updateTable();
            successNoty("Saved");
        }
    });
}

function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",//specific param here to distinguish?
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $("#editRow").modal("hide");
            updateTable();
            successNoty("Updated");
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1/why not use 2 different url ?

2/i believe you could use @pathvariable

3/You send the same form, so why bother having two method ?

Comment: What forces you to design it like that?

Comment: :D
Okay, having a different URL seems to be the only solution, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @RequestBody annotation:

```
@PutMapping("/users/{id}")
public void update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody User user) 
{
    service.update(user);
}
```

Comment: But the point here is you can not Request something in PUT method

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.